# statuscode and statecode mismatch even though both are explicitly set

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm getting an error when creating a service appointment entity through the SOAP webservice about a mismatch between statuscode and statecode:

> 4 is not a valid status code for state code
>   ServiceAppointmentState.Open on serviceappointment.

Essentially saying that [reserved (statuscode 4)](http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/entity-statecodes-and-statuscodes.html) isn't a member of the [Open state (statecode 1)](http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/entity-statecodes-and-statuscodes.html). Which is true, it's actually a member of the [Scheduled state (statecode 3)](http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/entity-statecodes-and-statuscodes.html) but in my request I'm correctly setting statecode to 3!

Does anyone know why my setting the serviceappointment to the Scheduled state is being ignored?

---

full request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
            <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>statecode</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
                     <a:Value>3</a:Value>
                  </b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>serviceid</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
                     <a:Id>c5b8179c-3cab-e211-ab0a-00155d1438e9</a:Id>
                     <a:LogicalName>service</a:LogicalName>
                     <a:Name i:nil="true" />
                  </b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>scheduledend</b:key>
                  <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:dateTime">2013-06-13T14:30:00</b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>statuscode</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
                     <a:Value>4</a:Value>
                  </b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>subject</b:key>
                  <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:string">Support handover</b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>scheduledstart</b:key>
                  <b:value xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="c:dateTime">2013-06-13T09:00:00</b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>py3_workpackageid</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
                     <a:Id>dc7008cf-2eab-e211-ab0a-00155d1438e9</a:Id>
                     <a:LogicalName>py3_workpackage</a:LogicalName>
                     <a:Name i:nil="true" />
                  </b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>customers</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="a:EntityCollection">
                     <a:Entities>
                        <a:Entity>
                           <a:Attributes>
                              <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                                 <b:key>partyid</b:key>
                                 <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
                                    <a:Id>050d25a8-03c9-e211-866e-00155d143602</a:Id>
                                    <a:LogicalName>account</a:LogicalName>
                                    <a:Name i:nil="true" />
                                 </b:value>
                              </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                           </a:Attributes>
                           <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
                           <a:FormattedValues />
                           <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
                           <a:LogicalName>activityparty</a:LogicalName>
                           <a:RelatedEntities />
                        </a:Entity>
                     </a:Entities>
                     <a:EntityName i:nil="true" />
                     <a:MinActiveRowVersion i:nil="true" />
                     <a:MoreRecords>false</a:MoreRecords>
                     <a:PagingCookie i:nil="true" />
                     <a:TotalRecordCount>0</a:TotalRecordCount>
                     <a:TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded>false</a:TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded>
                  </b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
               <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>resources</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="a:EntityCollection">
                     <a:Entities>
                        <a:Entity>
                           <a:Attributes>
                              <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                                 <b:key>partyid</b:key>
                                 <b:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
                                    <a:Id>3e17fce0-e9cd-e211-866e-00155d143602</a:Id>
                                    <a:LogicalName>systemuser</a:LogicalName>
                                    <a:Name i:nil="true" />
                                 </b:value>
                              </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                           </a:Attributes>
                           <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
                           <a:FormattedValues />
                           <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
                           <a:LogicalName>activityparty</a:LogicalName>
                           <a:RelatedEntities />
                        </a:Entity>
                     </a:Entities>
                     <a:EntityName i:nil="true" />
                     <a:MinActiveRowVersion i:nil="true" />
                     <a:MoreRecords>false</a:MoreRecords>
                     <a:PagingCookie i:nil="true" />
                     <a:TotalRecordCount>0</a:TotalRecordCount>
                     <a:TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded>false</a:TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded>
                  </b:value>
               </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            </a:Attributes>
            <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
            <a:FormattedValues xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
            <a:Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</a:Id>
            <a:LogicalName>serviceappointment</a:LogicalName>
            <a:RelatedEntities xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
         </entity>
      </Create>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

it appears the same error occasionally happens when deleting solutions from an organisation so I've had trouble researching the issue. All I've found is [this forum post](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.crm/programmatically-creating-a-service-appo/171570), but it doesn't seem to be resolved.

Comment: This sounds very much like the webservice object has a typo. I would place a small sum on the parsing/validation portion of the webservice having a copy-paste typo of some sort and that is just getting translated out to your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statecode` is a readonly property, you can't set its value when you create a new record.

To set the right value you need to use always a `SetStateRequest`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx

Conclusion: first you need to create the record (and it will be in open state) and after change its status to reserved.

Comment: ah slightly unintuitive but makes sense, thanks. I presume so but do the REST services have the same limitation as you wouldn't be able to use the SetStateRequest?

Comment: if you use REST endpoint to create the record you have the same limitation, and unfortunately they didn't implement to change the state by REST, still need to use SOAP

Comment: Worth checking though.. guess I'll just have to take the performance hit on this one. Ta