# Not able to create record in CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to create an Won Opportunity in CRM but I am getting following error.

error:

> Additional information: 3 is not a valid status code for state code
>   OpportunityState.Open on opportunity with Id
>   8e99128b-3ef0-e711-8145-e0071b6641f1.

Code:

```
 public void CreateOpportunity()
    {
        Entity opportunity = new Entity("opportunity");
        opportunity["name"] = "ABC";           
        opportunity["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(1);
        opportunity["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(3);
        crmService.Create(opportunity);
    }
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071698/5233410

Answer (score 1):

In CRM, status code is **read only**. You cannot set it dynamically when adding a record, thus you get the error in your question.

To get pass it, you need to use [SetStateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx).

You initialize a new class of the SetStateRequest and set it, from msdn example:

```
// Create the Request Object
SetStateRequest state = new SetStateRequest();

// Set the Request Object's Properties
state.State = new OptionSetValue((int)IncidentState.Active);
state.Status = 
    new OptionSetValue((int)incident_statuscode.WaitingforDetails);

// Point the Request to the case whose state is being changed
state.EntityMoniker = caseReference;

// Execute the Request
SetStateResponse stateSet = (SetStateResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(state);

// Check if the state was successfully set
Incident incident = _serviceProxy.Retrieve(Incident.EntityLogicalName, 
    _caseIncidentId, new ColumnSet(allColumns: true)).ToEntity<Incident>();

if (incident.StatusCode.Value == (int)incident_statuscode.WaitingforDetails)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Record state set successfully.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The request to set the record state failed.");
}
```

and the list of IncidentState values:

```
IncidentStateSNC.NEW                = "1";

IncidentStateSNC.IN_PROGRESS        = "2";

IncidentStateSNC.ACTIVE             = IncidentStateSNC.IN_PROGRESS;

IncidentStateSNC.ON_HOLD            = "3";

IncidentStateSNC.AWAITING_PROBLEM   = IncidentStateSNC.ON_HOLD;

IncidentStateSNC.AWAITING_USER_INFO = IncidentStateSNC.ON_HOLD;

IncidentStateSNC.AWAITING_EVIDENCE  = IncidentStateSNC.ON_HOLD;

IncidentStateSNC.RESOLVED           = "6";

IncidentStateSNC.CLOSED             = "7";

IncidentStateSNC.CANCELED           = "8";
```

there is a nice article here about [How to set the state on dynamic entity](https://www.powerobjects.com/2012/03/30/how-to-programmatically-set-the-status-code-field-of-a-dynamic-entity/) as well.

Comment: Thanks I understood what I have to do. Error got resolved.

Comment: This is true for most record types, but not opportunity. You need to use the specific WonOpportunity/LostOpportunity messages to set the state of an opportunity.

Comment: @vidhi how did you fix?

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot set the StateCode & StatusCode while creating opportunity records, System will Set default as Open
2. Like error says StatusCode 3 is not a valid combination for Open. [Read my SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605082/7920473)
3. SetStateRequest is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx#Remarks). So once opportunity is created, do an Update request with appropriate Won/Lost combo